# Convert Mysql select statement with joins to mulidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I can't seem to find a proper way to do the following:

I'm selecting values from * tables with joins, let's say:

```
SELECT templates.id as templates-id, template_fields.id as template_fields-id FROM templates JOIN template_fields ON templates.id = template_fields.template_id.
```

The result I get is the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [template_id] => 1
            [template_field_id] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [template_id] => 1
            [template_field_id] => 21
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [template_id] => 2
            [template_field_id] => 22
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [template_id] => 2
            [template_field_id] => 23
        )

)
```

But I need to have something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [template_fields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 21
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [template_fields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 22
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The class that's responsible for building these queries remembers the order of the joins. The first parameter in the columnalias (templates, template_fields) can be used to know which one has to be the subarray.

Here's how the class is used:

```
$result = $database->select('templates')->join('templatesfields')->getResult()->formattedOutput('');
```

The formatted output is something like this:

```
$formattedArray = array();

        foreach ($this->result as $row)
        {
            $ids = array();
            $tempColumnValuesArray = array();

            foreach ($row as $columnKey => $value)
            {
                $columnKeyExploded  = explode('-', $columnKey);
                $columnTable        = $columnKeyExploded[0];
                $columnColumnName   = $columnKeyExploded[1];

                if (!isset($formattedArray[$columnTable]))
                {
                    $formattedArray[$columnTable] = array();
                }

                if ($columnColumnName === 'id' && !isset($formattedArray[$columnTable][$value]))
                {
                    $formattedArray[$columnTable][$value] = array();
                    $ids[$columnTable] = $value;
                }

                if (!isset($ids[$columnTable]))
                {
                    $tempColumnValuesArray[$columnColumnName] = $value;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($tempColumnValuesArray)
                    {
                        array_merge($formattedArray[$columnTable][$ids[$columnTable]], $tempColumnValuesArray);
                        $tempColumnValuesArray = array();
                    }

                    $formattedArray[$columnTable][$ids[$columnTable]][$columnColumnName] = $value;
                }

            }
        }

        foreach ($formattedArray as $tableName => $rows)
        {
            /**
             * TEMP TEMP TEMP TEMP TEMP TEMP TEMP TEMP TEMP
             */

            if ($tableName == 'templates')
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach ($rows as $row)
                {
                    $formattedArray['templates'][$row['template_id']]['templates_fields'][] = $row;
                }
            }
        }

        return $formattedArray;
```

But this function can't use static parameters...

Is there any way to convert this flat array to a multidimensional array like the given example?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to change from first array to second one?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  It's quite simple, too.  Can you show your current code?

Comment: @AleksG I updated my question =)

Comment: is your first array of your post is `$result`?

Comment: That's the result of the query. It has to be reformatted to the second array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'template_id' => 1,
            'template_field_id' => 20
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'template_id' => 1,
            'template_field_id' => 21
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'template_id' => 2,
            'template_field_id' => 22
        ),

    3 => Array
        (
            'template_id' => 2,
            'template_field_id' => 23
        )

);

$newarr = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    $newarr[$val['template_id']][] = $val;
}

$i=0;
foreach($newarr as $k=>$v){
    foreach($v as $m){
      $newarr1[$i]['id']=  $m['template_id'];
      $newarr1[$i]['template_field_id'][]['id']=  $m['template_field_id'];
    }
    $i++;
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newarr1);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/hBHnM)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_column and array_search to search inside multidimension result array.

```
$arr = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'template_id' => 1,
            'template_field_id' => 20
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'template_id' => 1,
            'template_field_id' => 21
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'template_id' => 2,
            'template_field_id' => 22
        ),

    3 => Array
        (
            'template_id' => 2,
            'template_field_id' => 23
        )

);

   $resultArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $data){
     $index = array_search($data['template_id'], array_column($resultArr, 'id'));
     if($index !== false){
         if(is_array($resultArr[$index]["template_fields"]))
         array_push($resultArr[$index]["template_fields"],array("id"=>$data["template_field_id"]));
      else
         $resultArr[$index]["template_fields"] = array(array("id"=>$data["template_field_id"]));

    }else{
         $newData = array("id"=>$data['template_id'],"template_fields"=>array(array("id"=>$data["template_field_id"])));
         array_push($resultArr,$newData);
    }  
}
print_r($resultArr);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/f5Kb0)